# php regex to remove unwanted space within strings

Tags: php, regex, space

I have a long list of codes:

```
BR 1111 
BR 2222 
CO 3333
```

I need to remove the space from within them so they end up:

```
BR1111 
BR2222 
CO3333
```

I've tried this to no avail:

```
preg_replace('/(\D{2})\s(\d{4})')
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Thank you so much. I'm trying to add an HTML page with a form text area to add a list of these codes to clean:

```
<form name="f" action="clean.php" method="POST"> <textarea cols="70" rows="7" name="str" > <?php echo $str; ?> </textarea> <br /> <input type="submit" value=" Code Cleaner " style="font-size:18px; color:#ff0000;"> </form>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thx

Comment: Why do you need a regex? `$str = str_replace(" ", "", $str);`

Comment: @alro: the OP's question didn't show the strings on new lines, just sequentially: `BR 1111 BR 2222 CO 3333`, in which case, removing all spaces isn't ideal

Comment: Ah, I had not seen that that was edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex `/([A-Z]{2})\s+(\d{4})/` should work fine:

Basically - two letters from A-Z followed by 1 to unlimited spaces followed by a number of 4 digits.

```
preg_replace("/([A-Z]{2})\s+(\d{4})/", "$1$2", $string);
```

If you just want to remove all spaces, `str_replace(" ", "", $string)` or a regex of `/ +/` would do the trick:

```
str_replace(" ", "", $string);
```

or

```
preg_replace("/ +/", "", $string);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm trying to add an HTML page with a form text area to add a list of these codes to clean:

<form name="f" action="clean.php" method="POST"> <textarea cols="70" rows="7" name="str" > <?php echo $str; ?> </textarea> <br /> <input type="submit" value=" Code Cleaner " style="font-size:18px; color:#ff0000;"> </form>

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$string = preg_replace('/([A-Z]{2})\s*([0-9]+)/','$1$2',$string);
```

Tested with `BR 1111 BR 2222 CO 3333`, and it returned `'BR1111 BR2222 CO3333'`
Alternatively, if that list happens to be a simple csv, or txt file, you could use the following Vim command:

```
:%s/\([A-Z]\+\)\s*/\1/g
```

Just add a `c` flag at the end if you're not sure, and want to see every match before it's replaced:

```
:%s/\([A-Z]\+\)\s*/\1/gc
```

Press `y` to confirm, and replace (remove the spaces), `n` to skip

Comment: Why the down-vote? I wrote this answer, based on how the OP formatted the strings in his original answer (before some else edited it), which showed all chars on a single line

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove space character only, then you have two options:

1. Regex:

   ```
   $s = preg_replace("/ /", "", $s);
   ```
2. Non-regex:

   ```
   $s = str_replace(" ", "", $s);
   ```

However if you need to remove spaces just between two non-digit characters and 4 digits, then use:

```
$s = preg_replace("/(?<=\D{2}) (?=\d{4})/", "", $s);
```